# Can't get all BookMarkedRooms when using PrivateDataManager with (a)Smack. Always returns only the last bookmark

Tags: android, chat, smack, asmack, multiuserchat

I added 3-4 Persistent Conference rooms and try to get connect ever conference room at app start time but when i tried to get all bookmarked rooms it will just returns me one room.
and that room is last time added.

```
 muc = new MultiMUC(connection, "g2@conference.msngr.com");
        try {   
    muc.create("g2");
    Form form = muc.getConfigurationForm();
    Form submitForm = form.createAnswerForm();                
    FormField ff = new FormField("muc#roomconfig_persistentroom");
          ff.setType(FormField.TYPE_BOOLEAN);
          ff.addValue("0");
          ff.setRequired(true);
          ff.setLabel("Make Room Persistent?");
          submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_persistentroom", true);              
          List owners = new ArrayList();                  
          owners.add("userdev@msngr.com");  
          submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_roomowners", owners);
          muc.sendConfigurationForm(submitForm);
             Bookmarks bookmarks = new Bookmarks();
             BookmarkedConferenceImpl conference = new BookmarkedConferenceImpl("g2@conference.msngr.com");
             conference.setName("My Favorite Room");
             conference.setAutoJoin(true);            
             bookmarks.addBookmarkedConference(conference);  

                 try
                 {

                 PrivateDataManager manager = new PrivateDataManager(connection,"userdev@msngr.com");
                 manager.setPrivateData(bookmarks);          
                 }
                 catch (Exception e) {  }
```

but when i am try to get all BookMarkedRoom it return one last added Coference room.

```
 BookmarkManager bm = BookmarkManager.getBookmarkManager(connection);
              Collection<BookmarkedConference> rooms=bm.getBookmarkedConferences() ; 
            for(BookmarkedConference room:rooms){                   
                    MultiUserChat  muc = new MultiMUC(connection, room.getJid());
                    muc.join(uid);              
                    muc.addMessageListener(listener);

                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are always overwriting the Bookmarks PrivateData with the latest MUC that got created.

Instead of using the PrivateDataManager directly, use the specialized [BookmarkManager](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/bookmark/BookmarkManager.html) for this job. BookmarkManager comes with three methods that should do the job for you conviniently

- [`addBookmarkedConference()`](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/bookmark/BookmarkManager.html#addBookmarkedConference%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)
- [`getBookmarkedConferences()`](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/bookmark/BookmarkManager.html#getBookmarkedConferences%28%29)
- [`removeBookmarkedConference()`](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/bookmark/BookmarkManager.html#removeBookmarkedConference%28java.lang.String%29)